# Is a pass by value and move possibe in the C++ linear algebra library Eigen3?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I pass an Eigen matrix to a constructor. In accordance to the Eigen documentation, [pass by const reference](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicPassingByValue.html) is used.

However, clang-tidy suggest a modernized pass by value and move:

```
warning: pass by value and use std::move [modernize-pass-by-value]
Foo::Foo(const Eigen::Vector3d& bar) : bar_(bar) {};
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      Eigen::Vector3d                       std::move( )
```

Can pass by value and move be used with Eigen?

Comment: Why not try and find out. It is just a suggestion, you could choose to ignore it.

Comment: Sure, it is an option. However, Eigen is quite delicate about memory management. Even if a specific build works (e.g. GCC Debug), another might fail (e.g. Clang Release). Thus I'd be happy to be sure if pass by value/move is supported or not.

Comment: That should not be a problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: It will be a problem if you pass objects which require alignment (e.g., `Vector4d`) on a platform/compiler which does not support stack alignment. And it will be very inefficient, if you pass large fixed-sized objects (e.g., `Matrix<double, 10, 10>`).

Comment: @chtz I guess that answers it.
From the documentation:  [...] the reason is that these Eigen objects have alignment modifiers that aren't respected when they are passed by value.